# How to get duration time, average pace, distance in GoogleMaps

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I searched for a solution or hint how to get Duration,average pace and distance from GoogleMaps v2 api but without success for now. 
What I try to do is an App to track run activity and just show at real time relevant info about this run. 
Can anyone throw me a bone Please?